# Error en excel 1004: Error definido por la aplicación o el objeto en otra pc

Tags: excel, vba, macros, vb, microsoft-office

Resulta que hice una macro que automatiza el llenado de algunas celdas. En mi Laptop funciona excelente, pero al correr esta macro en otro computador se abre una ventana emergente que dice:
Se ha producido el error 1004 en tiempo de ejecucion:
Error definido por la aplicación o el objeto.

Este es el codigo de la macro que me esta dando problemas:

```
Public Sub Datos()

Range("E13").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).FormulaLocal = "=SUMA(" & ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Address & ":F14)" ' SubTotal
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).FormulaLocal = "=(" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Address & "*0.18)" '  ITBIS
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 1).FormulaLocal = "=(" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Address & "+" & ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1) & ")" 'ESTA ES LA LINEA QUE ME ESTA DANDO ERROR

' Cantidad de Productos
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).FormulaLocal = "=SUMA(" & ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -1).Address & ":D14)" ' Cantidad de Productos
```

Agradeceria mucho un poco de ayuda ya que no tengo idea de que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el valor de `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1)` cuando te da error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba hacer lo siguiente.

```
Public Sub Datos()

Range("E13").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).FormulaLocal = "=SUMA(" & ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Address & ":F14)" ' SubTotal
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).FormulaLocal = "=(" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Address & "*0.18)" '  ITBIS
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 1).FormulaLocal = "=(" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Address & "+" & ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Address & ")" 'ESTA ES LA LINEA QUE ME ESTA DANDO ERROR, completa ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1) con .Address

' Cantidad de Productos
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).FormulaLocal = "=SUMA(" & ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -1).Address & ":D14)" ' Cantidad de Productos
```